# NavLink is not rendering another page

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I use `NavLink` tag (`react-router-dom`) in navbar but when i click on navbar components url goes change but it not rendering another page, it shows the same page.

Here is my `App.js` file

```
export default function App() {
    return(
        <div>
            <NavBar />
            <BrowserRouter>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
                    <Route exact path="/about" component={About} />
                    <Route exact path="/contact" component={Contact} />
                </Switch>
            </BrowserRouter>
        </div>
    )
}
```

My `NavBar.js` file

```
export default function NavBar(){
    return(
        <div>
            <BrowserRouter>
                <NavLink to="/home">Home</NavLink>
                <NavLink to="/about">About</NavLink>
                <NavLink to="/contact">Contact</NavLink>
            </BrowserRouter>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the `NavBar` should be in same `BrowserRouter` that using for `Route`.

```js
export default function App() {
    return(
        <div>
            <BrowserRouter>
                <NavBar />
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
                    <Route exact path="/about" component={About} />
                    <Route exact path="/contact" component={Contact} />
                </Switch>
            </BrowserRouter>
        </div>
    )
}
```

```js
export default function NavBar(){
    return(
        <div>
            <NavLink to="/home">Home</NavLink>
            <NavLink to="/about">About</NavLink>
            <NavLink to="/contact">Contact</NavLink>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Here a working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-bose-66z69
I was writing the answer but you were faster :)